# Emacs org-mode source block incorrectly parsed as link in export (unable to resolve link)

Tags: python, emacs, org-mode

I'm unable to export an emacs org file with python source code blocks. Part of the code inside a properly executing source code block appears to be parsed as a link. The export fails with the error:

```
user-error: Unable to resolve link: "'Reading', 'Calibration'"
```

I have tried deleting the code that is parsed as a link. This did not resolve the issue.

Here is the only line that matches the "link":

```
df[['Reading', 'Calibration']]
```

There are no other instances of this text anywhere in the document. The code blocks all execute properly otherwise. Even after deleting this line, the error remains. Any suggestions how to resolve, or what this bug might be?

EDIT:

I understand why there is still this "link" with the code block deleted. At the end of the exported file I have the tangled code attached:

```
#+INCLUDE: "document.ipython" src python
```

Is there some way to suppress the interpretation of this tangled code as an org link?

Answer (score 0):

I've asked a similar question [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54533/org-mode-blocks-incorrectly-parsed-as-org-mode-markup/54536#54536). You might want to check whether there is a line starting with `*` inside your blocks. If this is the case, the source block has been interpreted as a headline, and what's follow as markup content. That's why `org-mode` is trying to resolve the fake link. You might prefix such line as depicted in the [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html#Literal-Examples) by a comma to solve the issue.